# Error implementing parse.com push notifications in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, parse-platform

Followed [parse.com quickstart guide for an existing WP8](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/windows_phone/existing) project and It's not working.

### Code:

```
public App()
    {
        // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Standard Silverlight initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();

        ParseClient.Initialize("ParseAppId", "ParseDotNetKey");
        this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            // This optional line tracks statistics around app opens, including push effectiveness:
            ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);

            // By convention, the empty string is considered a "Broadcast" channel
            // Note that we had to add "async" to the definition to use the await keyword
            await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
        };
    }
```

### Error:

```
$exception  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the        target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.  
at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_LocalSettings()  
at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper..ctor()  
at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper.get_Wrapper()  
at Parse.PlatformHooks.get_ApplicationSettings()  
at Parse.ParseClient.get_ApplicationSettings()  
at Parse.ParseClient.get_InstallationId()  
at Parse.ParseClient.Initialize(String applicationId, String dotnetKey)  
at MyApp.App..ctor()  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)  
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass32.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2c()  
at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)  
at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.CreateKnownObject(IntPtr nativeRootPeer, UInt32 customTypeId, String initializationString, IntPtr& nativePeer, UInt32 isCreatedByParser)}   System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
```

Don't know what's happening here.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and it looks like Parse uses some classes designed for Windows but not Windows Phone in the latest version of Parse.Phone.dll. The only solution I came up with is using an old version of parse for WP (1.2.16 in my case). Hope you'll find it useful

Comment: This is not the answer, I'll post my solution.

Comment: If you have a better solution feel free to share it with the community!